# How to display stored array from database

Tags: php, sql, arrays, forms, foreach

This is how I'm storing the array into my database (part of a bigger code):

```
 echo '<form action="" method="post">';

        for ($count = 0; $count < $_GET["entries"]; $count++)
        {
            echo  'Enter a beginning to ending date for the week: <input type="text" name="week"><br/>';
        }

        echo '<input type="submit" name="submit"></form>';
```

It's within a  tag, hence the echo.

I checked my database and I can see the first date, so it is being stored.

This is how I'm displaying my array (doesn't seem to work):

Where am I going wrong? Is it just the output or the input as well? I would really appreciate any suggestions for a possible answer. Thanks.

```
Current Specific Weeks: <?php 

    foreach ($currentWeeks as $currentWeeks)
    {
        echo "{$currentWeeks}\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Foreach mistake. You're using `$currentWeeks` for both the array and the element.

Answer (score 1):

Use different variable name in `foreach` loop

```
foreach ($currentWeeks as $week)
                          ^^^^^ // here
{
    echo "{$week}\n";
}
```